# How to set the delimiter of csv file as ; instead of default coma(,) in a shell script

Tags: shell, csv

```
I am running the below shell script
awk -F ' *[[:alnum:]_]*: *' 'BEGIN         {h="bla;blaa;blaaa;blaaaaa;blaaaaa1;bla111;bla2;bla3;blaaa3;bla4"; print h; n=split(h,F,/;/)}
                         function pr() {if(F[1] in A) {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)printf "%s%s",A[F[i]],(i<n)?";":RS}}
                         /insert_job/  {pr(); delete A}
                                       {for(i in F){if($0~"^"F[i])A[F[i]]=$2}}
                         END           {pr()}' infile > outfile.csv
```

The output file is output.csv, where coma is delimiter.Since one of the column contains values where coma is also there, the output.csv gets messed up.Please help me to understand how can i set the delimiter as ;(semicolon)

Comment: add `OFS=";";` to your `BEGIN` action, the OutputFieldSeparator.

Comment: @LarsFischer where do I put it.
I changed the code as shown below, it still works the same way.I need the csv file to recognize ; but comas are winning still
`awk -F ' *[[:alnum:]_]*: *' 'BEGIN         {h="bla;blaa;blaaa;blaaaaa;blaaaaa1;bla111;bla2;bla3;blaaa3;bla4"; print h; n=split(h,F,/;/); OFS=";"}`